Perform drag and drop event to all clients with socket.io
it's the first time i'm working with node.js, express and socket.io and i'm trying to perform a simple drag and drop option for all connected clients. Drag and drop is working but it is not rerendered on my clients browser.
If one client is performing a drag and drop my other clients get following console ouput:

Data received
null
undefinded
null

This is what i've done so far:
// server.js
const path = require('path');

const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.get('/management', function(req, res) {
    const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'client.html');
    res.sendFile(filePath);
    clientIp = req.socket.remoteAddress;
    console.log("Client " +clientIp+ " joined Management.");
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('user connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
      console.log('user disconnected');
    });
});


io.on('connection', (socket) => {
        socket.on('drop', (data,dropzone) => {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(dropzone)
        socket.broadcast.emit('drop', data);
        socket.broadcast.emit('drop', dropzone);
        });
});

server.listen(port, function() {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
});

// client.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<style>
.device {
  width: 350px;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
</style>

<script src = "/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>


<body>

  <div>
    <p id="User ID" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">User</p>
  </div>


  <div class="device" id="D1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">Drop
  </div>

</body>

<script>

  const socket = io();

  function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  }

  function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
  // console.log(ev.target.id)
  }

  function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    const data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text"); //User Element
    let dropzone = ev.target;
    socket.emit('drop', data);
    socket.emit('drop', dropzone);
  }

  socket.on('drop', (data,dropzone) => {
    console.log('Data received');
    console.log(data)
    console.log(dropzone) 
    let temp = document.getElementById(data);
    console.log(temp) 
    dropzone.appendChild(temp);
    // dropzoneid.id.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  });

</script>

</html>

Client Console Log Image
Server Terminal Console Output
I'm very thankful for any ideas and help!
EDIT: I think i found a solution and now the drag and drop is rendered on all clients :) This what i've done. Maybe there is a better and more elegant way how to do this.
// server.js
    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
        socket.on('drop', (data) => {
        console.log('User received from client: ' + data);
        socket.broadcast.emit('drop',data);
        });
});

// Client
const socket = io();

  function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  }

  function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
  // console.log(ev.target.id)
  }

  function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    // User HTML element
    const user = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text"); 
    // Dropzone HTML element
    let target = ev.target.id;
    // Show drag and drop event on client who performed
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(user));
    // Collect user and target
    var details = {user:user, target:target};
    // Send details to server
    socket.emit('drop', details)
  }

  socket.on('drop', (data) => {
    console.log('Data received from server: ' + data)
    console.log('User element: ' + data.user)
    console.log('Target element: ' + data.target)
    let user_element = document.getElementById(data.user)
    let drop_element = document.getElementById(data.target);
    // console.log(temp) 
    drop_element.appendChild(user_element);
    // dropzoneid.id.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  });

